# Javascript stopwatch want the clock element to be a div not an input

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have the following code, As you can see in the HTML I have a div with id=clock and an input element also with id=clock, basically if i remove the div or comment it out, the input element works fine, on the html page the clock in the input element will display the time, I would prefer it to use the div element for styling purposes; however, if i comment out the input element and use the div it does not count up, I think I understand why but I cant seem to fix it. Can someone help explain how I can do this using the following code?

```js
var flagclock = 0;
var flagstop = 0;
var stoptime = 0;
var splitcounter = 0;
var currenttime;
var splitdate = '';
var output;
var clock;

// Start-Stop Function

function startstop() {
  var startstop = document.getElementById('startstopbutton');
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if (flagclock == 0) {
    startstop.value = 'Stop';
    flagclock = 1;
    counter(starttime);
  } else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
  }
}

//Increment function     

function counter(starttime) {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if (flagstop == 1) {
    timediff = timediff + stoptime
  }
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.value = formattime(timediff, '');
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 10);
  } else {
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    stoptime = timediff;
  }
}

function formattime(rawtime, roundtype) {
  if (roundtype == 'round') {
    var ds = Math.round(rawtime / 100) + '';
  } else {
    var ds = Math.floor(rawtime / 100) + '';
  }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime / 60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  if (min >= 60) {
    startstop();
  }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if (sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '') {
    sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  } else {
    sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  }
  min = min + '';
  if (min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '') {
    min = min.charAt(min.length - 2) + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  } else {
    min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  }
  return min + ':' + sec + ':' + ds;
}

// reset function      

function resetclock() {
  flagstop = 0;
  stoptime = 0;
  splitdate = '';
  window.clearTimeout(refresh);
  output.value = '';
  splitcounter = 0;
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    var resetdate = new Date();
    var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
    counter(resettime);
  } else {
    clock.value = "00:00:0";
  }
}

//Split function

function splittime() {
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    if (splitdate != '') {
      var splitold = splitdate.split(':');
      var splitnow = clock.value.split(':');
      var numbers = new Array();
      var i = 0
      for (i; i < splitold.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = new Array();
        numbers[i][0] = splitold[i] * 1;
        numbers[i][1] = splitnow[i] * 1;
      }
      if (numbers[1][1] < numbers[1][0]) {
        numbers[1][1] += 60;
        numbers[0][1] -= 1;
      }
      if (numbers[2][1] < numbers[2][0]) {
        numbers[2][1] += 10;
        numbers[1][1] -= 1;
      }
      var mzeros = (numbers[0][1] - numbers[0][0]) < 10 ? '0' : '';
      var szeros = (numbers[1][1] - numbers[1][0]) < 10 ? '0' : '';
      output.value += '\t+' + mzeros + (numbers[0][1] - numbers[0][0]) + ':' + szeros + (numbers[1][1] - numbers[1][0]) + ':' + (numbers[2][1] - numbers[2][0]) + '\n';
    }
    splitdate = clock.value;
    output.value += (++splitcounter) + '. ' + clock.value + '\n';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="startstopbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btn" id='btn' value="Start" onclick="startstop()" ;>
<input id="resetbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btnRst1" id='btnRst1' value="Reset" onclick="resetclock()" ;>
<div id="clock" class="timerClock">00:00:00</div><br>
<!-- Clock 2 -->
<input id="clock" class="timerClock" type="text" value="00:00:0" style="text-align: center;" readonly=""><br>
<!-- Split Button -->
<input id="splitbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px; margin-right: 170px" type="button" value="Split Time" onclick="splittime();">
<!-- output for split times -->
<textarea id="output" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: instead of "clock.value" use "clock.innerText" for the div. Also, mind ids have to be unique so change the div id to clock2 or something like that

Comment: This worked, innerHTML was the problem cant believe I missed it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `clock.value` to set the contents of the `<input>` element. This will not work for `<div>` elements; you will need to use `innerHTML` instead:

```js
clock = document.getElementById('clock'); //div#clock

// ...

clock.innerHTML = formattime(timediff, '');
```

Comment: innerHTML was the problem, ive changed it and it works fine now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> have a div with id=clock and an input element also with id=clock,

This is bad. `ID` have to be UNIQUE. This is why when you have both present ( with same id ) the counter doesn't work. It selects just the first element with id `clock` which is the `div`.

It doesn't select the `input`. As you can see `getElementById` is singular. If you want to select both of them, add a common class and select that with `getElementsByClassName(className)` ( notice the plural `Elements` compared to `Element` from the ID selector ) or `querySelectorAll(className)` and loop through them.

I added `clock-div` as the id on the `div`

Also. `div` element does not have a `value` attribute ( unlike `input` ). To get or edit/manipulate the text inside a `div` element you should use `div.innerText` instead of `div.value`.  As a side note, div can have HTML inside it (input can't) . You can access it with `div.innerHTML`

So basically you need to change the id of the div ( if you also want to keep the input ) and change `clock.value` to `clock.innerText` everywhere.

Another option would be to keep both input and div. And assign the value of the input to the div.innerText.

```js
var flagclock = 0;
var flagstop = 0;
var stoptime = 0;
var splitcounter = 0;
var currenttime;
var splitdate = '';
var output;
var clock;

// Start-Stop Function

function startstop() {
  var startstop = document.getElementById('startstopbutton');
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if (flagclock == 0) {
    startstop.value = 'Stop';
    flagclock = 1;
    counter(starttime);
  } else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
  }
}

//Increment function     

function counter(starttime) {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  // change here id 
  clock = document.getElementById('clock-div');
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if (flagstop == 1) {
    timediff = timediff + stoptime
  }
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.innerText = formattime(timediff, '');
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 10);
  } else {
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    stoptime = timediff;
  }
}

function formattime(rawtime, roundtype) {
  if (roundtype == 'round') {
    var ds = Math.round(rawtime / 100) + '';
  } else {
    var ds = Math.floor(rawtime / 100) + '';
  }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime / 60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  if (min >= 60) {
    startstop();
  }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if (sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '') {
    sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  } else {
    sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  }
  min = min + '';
  if (min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '') {
    min = min.charAt(min.length - 2) + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  } else {
    min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  }
  return min + ':' + sec + ':' + ds;
}

// reset function      

function resetclock() {
  flagstop = 0;
  stoptime = 0;
  splitdate = '';
  window.clearTimeout(refresh);
  output.value = '';
  splitcounter = 0;
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    var resetdate = new Date();
    var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
    counter(resettime);
  } else {
    clock.innerText = "00:00:0";
  }
}

//Split function

function splittime() {
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    if (splitdate != '') {
      var splitold = splitdate.split(':');
      var splitnow = clock.value.split(':');
      var numbers = new Array();
      var i = 0
      for (i; i < splitold.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = new Array();
        numbers[i][0] = splitold[i] * 1;
        numbers[i][1] = splitnow[i] * 1;
      }
      if (numbers[1][1] < numbers[1][0]) {
        numbers[1][1] += 60;
        numbers[0][1] -= 1;
      }
      if (numbers[2][1] < numbers[2][0]) {
        numbers[2][1] += 10;
        numbers[1][1] -= 1;
      }
      var mzeros = (numbers[0][1] - numbers[0][0]) < 10 ? '0' : '';
      var szeros = (numbers[1][1] - numbers[1][0]) < 10 ? '0' : '';
      output.value += '\t+' + mzeros + (numbers[0][1] - numbers[0][0]) + ':' + szeros + (numbers[1][1] - numbers[1][0]) + ':' + (numbers[2][1] - numbers[2][0]) + '\n';
    }
    splitdate = clock.innerText;
    output.innerText += (++splitcounter) + '. ' + clock.value + '\n';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="startstopbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btn" id='btn' value="Start" onclick="startstop()" ;>
<input id="resetbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px;" type="button" name="btnRst1" id='btnRst1' value="Reset" onclick="resetclock()" ;>
<div id="clock-div" class="timerClock">00:00:00</div><br>
<!-- Clock 2 -->
<input id="clock" class="timerClock" type="text" value="00:00:0" style="text-align: center;" readonly=""><br>
<!-- Split Button -->
<input id="splitbutton" class="buttonZ" style="width: 120px; margin-right: 170px" type="button" value="Split Time" onclick="splittime();">
<!-- output for split times -->
<textarea id="output" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi, so for demonstration purposes I included both; however, when actually using the code I only will be using one of the options, not both. the innerHTML change has worked! thanks

Comment: Even for demonstration purposes you should not use duplicate IDs :) . Glad i could help. Use `innerText` if you just add plain text. Use `innerHTML` when you actually add HTML. Don't forget to rate/accept my answer. THank you